# Parse error when creating function without parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a function without parameters that create a list comprehension. When I try to run the code, I get a parse error and it fails to compile and I have no idea why.

I keep trying to run it on the terminal but it won't work.

This is my code:

```
outfits = let pants = ["jeans", "khaki", "leggings"]
              shirts = ["white shirt", "grey turtleneck", "pink polo", "green hoodie"]
              shoes = ["brogues", "converse", "sandals", "adidas"]

outfits1 = [ (x, y, z) | z <- pants, y <- shirts, x <- shoes ]
```

This is the error that comes up:

```
warmup.hs:7:11: error: parse error on input ‘outfits1’
  |
7 |           outfits1 = [ (x, y, z) | z <- pants, y <- shirts, x <- shoes ]
  |           ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Where is the `in` accompanying the `let`?

Comment: There's no such thing as a function without parameters. `outfits1` is just a list.

Answer (score 6):

Without the `let` expression, you would simply write

```
outfits = [ (x, y, z) | z <- ["jeans", "khaki", "leggings"], y <- ["white shirt", "grey turtleneck", "pink polo", "green hoodie"], x <- ["brogues", "converse", "sandals", "adidas"] ]
```

A `let` expression requires two parts: the local bindings immediately following the keyword `let`, and the expression which uses those bindings, following the keyword `in`:

```
outfits = let pants = ["jeans", "khaki", "leggings"]
              shirts = ["white shirt", "grey turtleneck", "pink polo", "green hoodie"]
              shoes = ["brogues", "converse", "sandals", "adidas"]
          in [ (x, y, z) | z <- pants, y <- shirts, x <- shoes ]
```

Alternately, you can write this using a `where` clause, which puts the "main" expression first:

```
outfits = [ (x, y, z) | z <- pants, y <- shirts, x <- shoes ]
              where pants = ["jeans", "khaki", "leggings"]
                    shirts = ["white shirt", "grey turtleneck", "pink polo", "green hoodie"]
                    shoes = ["brogues", "converse", "sandals", "adidas"]
```

---

### `Applicative` instead of list comprehension

I would write this using the `Applicative` instance for lists instead, using the 3-tuple constructor `(,,)`, which lets you do away with boilerplate variables `x`, `y`, and `z`.

```
outfits = (,,) <$> ["jeans", "khaki", "leggings"]
               <*> ["white shirt", "grey turtleneck", "pink polo", "green hoodie"]
               <*> ["brogues", "converse", "sandals", "adidas"]
```

You can still use either a `let` expression or a `where` clause to provide names for each component of an outfit:

```
outfits = let pants = ["jeans", "khaki", "leggings"]
              shirts = ["white shirt", "grey turtleneck", "pink polo", "green hoodie"]
              shoes = ["brogues", "converse", "sandals", "adidas"]
          in (,,) <$> pants <*> shirts <*> shoes
```

or

```
outfits = (,,) <$> pants <*> shirts <*> shoes
              where pants = ["jeans", "khaki", "leggings"]
                    shirts = ["white shirt", "grey turtleneck", "pink polo", "green hoodie"]
                    shoes = ["brogues", "converse", "sandals", "adidas"]
```

---

If `... <$> ... <*> ... <*> ...` looks too esoteric, you can give the pattern a more descriptive name:

```
outfits = mixAndMatch pants shirts shoes
           where pants = ["jeans", "khaki", "leggings"]
                 shirts = ["white shirt", "grey turtleneck", "pink polo", "green hoodie"]
                 shoes = ["brogues", "converse", "sandals", "adidas"]
                 mixAndMatch a b c = (,,) <$> a <*> b <*> c
```

Comment: `mixAndMatch = liftA3 (,,)`, which might be more palatable to inline even if you don't like applicative style.

Comment: or just [`zip3`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip3). Jumping into applicative for someone who's still learning the syntax might be a bit much.

Comment: @rampion `zip3` doesn't compute a cross product of the three lists.